# 'Thanks' page similar in style to table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, typography, thesis

I would like to add a 'thanks' page to my thesis. I did this very easy, just a bold and bigger heading, then the text. Since the table of contents is on the next page (a right page in this two-sided document), both the 'thanks' page and the table of contents are visible simultaneously. Therefore, i would like to use the same style as the table of contents (size and font of heading, vertical space to the top, vertical space below the heading).
I can do this by hand, but how is this done properly?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,titlepage,parskip=half]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\author{Foo Bar}
\title{A foo bar for a new foo bar baz}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\thispagestyle{plain}
{\bfseries\Large Thanks}

\kant[1-2]

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\chapter{Baz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Thanks/tableofcontents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\chapter*{Thanks}
```

instead of

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
{\bfseries\Large Thanks}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not think of this, because i did not wanted to have an toc entry, but i forgot about chapter* (with an asterisk)